# Trying to read NetCDF file as a raster but NA values change

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a NetCDF file as a raster in R. The data I'm working with is SST data from the NOAA Ocean Color Laboratory. I've opened the file in the program "SeaDAS", so I know the issue is not with the original file.

My code to read the file looks like this:

```
library(raster)
sst.nc<-raster("may2015_sst_monthly.nc")
proj4string(sst.nc)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
plot(sst.nc)
```

For some reason the raster has assigned values to the landmasses (see picture), which should be "NA". Anyone know what I need to do to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Have you checked what value those land areas have been given, as opposed to just looking at them on a plot?

Comment: @rosscova yes, I did

Comment: And what value was it? You specify that it's not `NA`, but knowing what that value is tells a big part of the story. If NetCDF is assigning a numeric value, it seems certain it would be a fairly logical one (in that it should be reliably distinguishable from all others), which makes @Jack Ballard's answer seem reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible instead of NA it's flagged it as some very large number, say 67676 (or perhaps a very large negative number). Then you could just do:

```
sst.nc[sst.nc==67676]=NA
```

And if you can't figure out the exact number for whatever reason (sometimes it has decimal points going out to 16 digits) you could just pick a large number clearly out of range of your data:

```
sst.nc[sst.nc>60000]=NA
```

Comment: you're right! It's really strange that when I opened the file in SeaDAS, the values were "NA". But in R, all land-based cells were assigned the value '45.'